# Что значит число 101 в getting started tutorials

Tags: javascript, java, c++, php, c#

Что значит число 101 в getting started tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Английская википедия](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101_(term)) утверждает, что это число показывает начальный уровень знаний.